# How to install pyarrow on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

Created Virtual environment (Python 3.7.0) and tried installing `pyarrow`:
`pip3.7 install --no-cache pyarrow` and getting error:

```
Collecting pyarrow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/2d/11751c477e4e7f4bb07ac7584aafabe0d0608c170e4bff67246d695ebdbe/pyarrow-0.9.0.tar.gz (8.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.5MB 383kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-install-3p7vvogb/pyarrow/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-install-3p7vvogb/pyarrow/
```

Tried installing `Cython` and running again `pip3.7 install --no-cache pyarrow`, this time got different error at the end:

```
Command "/Users/myuser/python/venv/p3/bin/python3 -u -c 
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=
'/private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-install-3a5y_ug4/pyarrow/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-record-tw4inr9f/install-record.txt
 --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/myuser/python/venv/p3/include/site/python3.7/pyarrow" 
 failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xy/b__x_l9n1kl9_llyngq1cvddqsd9bn/T/pip-install-3a5y_ug4/pyarrow/
```

Answer (score 4):

Pyarrow currently doesn't support python 3.7. They are [working on it](https://github.com/apache/arrow/issues/1125).

Comment: This is still true